# Canyon Ultimate R8000 front derailleur - can't get low enough

Tags: chain, derailleur-front

I have a Canyon Ultimate CF SL.

I have installed an R8000 Ultegra front derailleur. I am finding that even when the limit screw is dialed right out that when in the little-big combo (little front, big rear) the chain is still scuffing on the inside edge of the derailleur cage.

I have tried dialing out the lower limit screw, ensuring there is no cable tension, and ensuring it's properly aligned with the chainset. The chainset is 6800 50-34.

Any ideas what is going on and how I can rectify this issue?

Comment: Loosen the clamp on the downtube and twist the derailer slightly.  Often it has to be a hair non-parallel to work in such extreme cases.

Comment: Can you post a photo? Cam you see any FD parts touching the frame, like spring or inner cage plate?

Answer (score 4):

Amateur hour. Turns out my K-Edge chain catcher was actually blocking the derailler from moving into the lower position. It looks like this chain catcher is not compatible without modification for use with R8000.

Comment: Excellent finding - thank you for sharing that.  Consider trimming the chain catcher so the front mech can move a bit further?